# Где ошибка в логике обновления токенов?

Tags: android, время

Пытаюсь уменьшить кол-во запросов на сервер путем просчета времени после получения токенов и отправки запроса на обновление токенов в обход основного запроса. Например, было:
запрос на получение информации -> в ответ сервер сказал что у меня кончился access_token -> шлем запрос на обновление токена -> запрос на получение информации

пытаюсь сделать:

условие для проверки времени -> обновляем токен/запрос на получение информации

почему-то не получается сделать то что я хочу, потому что условие не срабатывает. Сделал так:

```
if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()) == sp.getLong("expires_in", 0)) {
MySingleton.getInstance().updateToken(sp.getString("refresh_token", ""), 1);
} else {
MySingleton.getInstance().getPersonalData();
}
```

когда эти две переменные были равны, то приложение все-равно послало запрос на получение информации и получило ее. Всего токен живет пол часа. Пробовал отследить время, которое проходит после получения токена через логи:

```
Log.i("m", String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis())) + "->" + String.valueOf(sp.getLong("expires_in", 0)) + "---->>" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - sp.getLong("expires_in", 0)));
```

и в итоге получается что 1800 секунд = 30 минутам, все вроде получается логично, но почему условие не сработало?) Не могу понять в чем я ошибся.

Comment: по вашему условию текущее количество миллисекунд должно быть равно(==) количеству миллисекунд истечения токена(что маловероятно), почему бы в условие не заменить знак `==` на знак `>=`?

Comment: UPD: ок, только щас заметил что у вас конвертация в секунды, но тем не менее, точное сравнение тут не особо к месту.

Comment: @ermak0ff, вы хотите сказать что лучший вариант для меня это просто знак `>`?

Comment: да, ведь вам не обязательно точно равенство секунд(вам лишь нужно убедится что время истечения токена прошло). плюс `sp.getLong("expires_in", 0)` точно возвращает секунды?

Comment: он возвращает utc

Comment: т.е. получается что вы сравниваете секунды с миллисекундами.

Comment: хм... а ведь вы правы, и нужно вместо `toSeconds` взять `toMillis`?

Comment: да, условие должно быть такого вида:`if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= sp.getLong("expires_in", 0))`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90862/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-ermak0ff).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще выбранный способ обновления/работы с api выглядит извращением/костылем.
Очень рекомендую перейти на Retrofit 2 и юзать Interceptor для перехвата протухания токена

Пример кода:

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private Context mContext;
private InternalRemoteRepository mRemoteRepository;
private Gson mGson;


public AuthorizationInterceptor(Context pContext, RemoteRepository pRemoteRepository, Gson pGson) {
    mContext = pContext;
    mRemoteRepository = (InternalRemoteRepository) pRemoteRepository;
    mGson = pGson;
}

@Override
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    if (!Network.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
        throw new NetworkException(mContext.getString(R.string.internet_connection_not_available));
    }

    Response response;
    try {
        response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new NetworkException(e.getMessage());
    }

    ResponseBody body = response.body();
    String bodyValue = body.string();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(bodyValue)) {
        RPCResponse result = mGson.fromJson(bodyValue, RPCResponse.class);
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            switch (result.getErrorCode()) {
                case ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                case ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND_AUTH:
                case ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD:
                case ERROR_ACCOUNT_NOT_SUPPORT:
                    throw new AuthorizationException(result.getMessage(), result.getErrorCode());
                case ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS:
                case ERROR_ACCESS_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND:
                case ERROR_ACCESS_DIED:
                    mRemoteRepository
                            .reAuthorization()
                            .subscribe(success -> {
                                if (!success) {
                                    throw new AuthorizationException(result.getMessage(), result.getErrorCode());
                                }
                            }, pThrowable -> {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE);
                                mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                            });
                    break;
                case ERROR_REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN:
                    mRemoteRepository
                            .refreshToken()
                            .subscribe(success -> {
                                if (!success) {
                                    mRemoteRepository
                                            .reAuthorization()
                                            .subscribe(resuccess -> {
                                                if (!resuccess) {
                                                    throw new AuthorizationException(result.getMessage(), result.getErrorCode());
                                                }
                                            }, pThrowable -> {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                                intent.setAction(AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE);
                                                mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                    break;
                case ERROR_INTERNAL_SERVER:
                    throw new UnknownServerException(result.getMessage());
                default:
                    throw new UnknownException(result.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return response
            .newBuilder()
            .body(ResponseBody.create(body.contentType(), bodyValue))
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: я и так на ретрофите )

Comment: Ну тогда задача облегчается, код сверху почти для oauth, был еще точно для него, но не могу найти

Comment: а разве нельзя путем просчета времени протухания токена, уменьшить кол-во запросов на сервер?

Comment: А зачем вообще считать то его? отправил запрос получил что токен протух, сохранил реквест с данными, отправил запрос на рефреш, получил токен и с новым токеном сохраненный запрос отправил, и будет счастье.

Comment: да у меня так было раньше, но суть в том что можно я думаю уменьшить кол-во запросов на сервер если считать время протухания

Comment: 1 лишний запрос в 30 мин?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91027/discussion-between---and-andrew-goroshko).

Comment: нет не лишний, идет проверка, и если токен протух то шлется запрос на обновление токена, минуя запрос на получение инфы где ответом будет сообщение о протухании токена